# What is the probability that for two randomly chosen natural numbers $a$ and $b$ the number $\frac {a}{b}$ is natural?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

I know about famous result that the probability that two randomly chosen natural numbers are relatively prime is $\dfrac {6}{{\pi}^2}$:

Then the probability that they are not coprime would be $1-\dfrac {6}{{\pi}^2}$.

But if we want them to form a natural number only the case when denominator is equal $1$ is the case where numerator and denominator are relatively prime and for all other denominators the numerator and denominator are not relatively prime.

So the answer maybe should combine in itself the probability for coprimality and for non-coprimality.

I really do not know how to answer the question:

> What is the probability that for two randomly chosen natural numbers $a$ and $b$ the number $\dfrac {a}{b}$ is natural number?

Comment: What is the implied probability distribution on the natural numbers? A uniform distribution is not possible.

Comment: @RoryDaulton With these questions you usually take a uniform distribution on $\{1\dots n\}$, find the probability, and then let $n\to\infty$. The wording is a little informal.

Comment: Marcel is Correct.......................

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly the logic here, we should consider the problem for a finite set $\{1,...,n\}$ and then take $n\to \infty$.

Ok. So there are $n^2$ possible pairs $(a,b)$ in this set.

For each $b$, the ratio $a/b$ is natural if $a$ is a multiple of $b$. In our set there are roughly $n/b$ such multiples. So the number of pairs we are looking for is 
$$\sum_{b=1}^n\frac{n}{b}=nH_n$$
where we have a harmonic number.

The probability will then be $H_n/n$ which tends to zero as $n\to\infty$.